# BibTeX .bst file: make author's last name uppercase, leave first name intact?

Tags: bibtex, capitalization

How do you set up your BibTeX style file (`.bst`) so that it makes author's surnames (last names) uppercase?

Example of what I want:

> SILVERMAN, David. *Interpreting qualitative data: methods for analysing
>   talk, text, and interaction.* 2nd ed. London [etc.]: Sage, 2002. 325 p.
>   ISBN 0-7619-6865-2.

I've made a custom BibTeX `.bst` file for my needs. My current `format.names.author` is as follows: http://pastebin.com/efsgrwDR

Comment: Could you please give us your *complete* .bst file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also recommend that you run the program makebst.tex through LaTeX. One of the questions that comes up early is the font to use for the rendering of surnames. Choose the option "small caps" (I know, this isn't exactly what you want, but bear with me). After you're done with the makebst program, open the resulting bst file and search for the command `"\textsc{"` inside the function {scaps}; replace the string `textsc` with `MakeUppercase`, leave everything else unchanged, save the file, and try it out on your bibliography. Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect using `makebst` is the easiest way out. Just install [`custom-bib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) and read the documentation. It will ask you a series of questions and generate a `.bst` file that fits your needs.