# Problem in bibtex style?

Tags: bibtex

I'm confusing about the reference in bibtex, I'm looking for a bibtex style such as given format,

[2] Bernoulli, D. Exposition of a new theory on the measurement of risk. *Econometrica*
22, 1, pp. 23–36, **1954**.

I tried acm style but in this style, the year of the journal are not at the end of the reference and I couldn't understand but the names are all caps.

[2] BERNOULLI, D., Exposition of a new theory on the measurement of risk. Econometrica
22, 1 (1954), pp. 23–36.

Is there any bibtex style which has this format, or how can I make some arrangement in the style format??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a style guide for this style?  Providing only one entry type typically doesn't help much.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no special style guide, I have just some examples for books and journals. But the main properties are 1)using numerical cite 2)The year must be at the end of the reference and bold 3) The surname shouldn't be all caps.

Comment: Why not deal with the package `biblatex`, it may be a little more flexible. Or the `custom-bib` package allows to create a new style with your own options.

Comment: And books must(?) look different in some respects from how journals are formatted, right?  If you only need to create 'styles' for articles and books (and not conference proceedings, or essays in books), then `biblatex` is a good way to go.  To implement a very full set of entry types will take much more time.  (The ideal solution, as you rightly hope, is that someone has already implemented the style -- but if even you don't have a name for it, it may well not exist....)

Comment: This a very new style which is suggested my institute, because of this I couldn't find a written bibtex style before. You are absolutely right, I have to create a style but for now  if I want to use ACM style, How can I change the just only year?? Is there any practical way to change it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an (easy) way to create or personalize .bst files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96174/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-or-personalize-bst-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, defined with `biblatex` and the `numeric` style. I could only manage the `article` (and alike) entry type, since I don't know what are the specifications for  `book`, for instance. I added an `issue` field to your item, to be able to format it in a sensible way (date and issue are mixed in the original definitions of biblatex); of course this formatting is easy to change, but I didn't like the original formatting after the year had been moved at the end.

A number of rarely used fields may appear after the year (ISBN, url, &c).

The names are printed in small caps, but that is easy to change: delete the two `\scshape` commands in `\DeclareNameFormat`. I use the `xpatch` package.

```
\documentclass{article}%mkbib
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting = nyt, firstinits]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bernou,
author = {Dino Bernoulli},
title = {Exposition of a new theory on the measurement of risk},
journaltitle = {Econometrica},
date = {1954},
volume = {22},
number = {1},
issuetitle = {Spring},
pages = {23--36},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\xpatchbibdriver{article}{%
\usebibmacro{note+pages}}
{%
\usebibmacro{note+pages}
\setunit*{\mdseries\addcomma\space}
\usebibmacro{date}}{}{}
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
\iffirstinits
{\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{\scshape#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}%
{\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{\scshape#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}%
\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{#1\isdot}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}
%
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
\mkbibbold{\printdate}}%
%
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
\usebibmacro{journal}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\iffieldundef{series}
{}
{\newunit
\printfield{series}%
\setunit{\addspace}}%
\usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
\setunit{\addspace}%
\usebibmacro{issue}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}
\newunit}
%
\newbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
\printfield{volume}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{number}%
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
\printfield{eid}}

\begin{document}

 \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! It would be great :)