# What does "Reference Component Tags" do in makebst?

Tags: custom-bib, bibitem

I am making my own latex bibliography style with *makebst* (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/96179/175861). I chose to incude REVTeX data fields.
One of the last selections I have to make is

```
<<REFERENCE COMPONENT TAGS:
(*) No reference component tags in the \bibitem entries
(b) Reference component tags like \bibinfo in the content of \bibitem
```

What does this mean? How are the two options different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation file [`merlin.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/merlin.pdf) has slightly more info on p. 20

> **Reference component tagging**: apply structure to the `\bibitem` contents.
>
> `--`            no tagging.
>
> `bibinfo`   apply tags like `\bibinfo`, and `\eprint` to the fields of data in the content of the `\bibitem` statement.

and later on p. 48

> If  reference  component  tagging  is  enabled,  we  apply  tags  like `\bibinfo` and `\eprint` to the fields of data in the content of the `\bibitem` statement.  We also ensure  that  these  commands  have  a  default  meaning  within  the  scope  of  the `thebibliography` environment.  The default definitions simply print the field and ignore the tag.  However,  other programs or packages might make use of the tag information to separate authors from title, for example.

Indeed the `.bst` file will add the following definition to the `thebibliography` preamble

```
\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
```

The history section on p. 5 also mentions `\bibinfo` briefly

> An additional feature that derived from Carlisle’s work on REVTeX is the tagging of the text entries in the bibliography.  This means the volume number  is  given  as `\bibinfo{volume}{5}`. Normally  only  the  number  5  is printed, but another program could use this to reconstruct the original database entries.

---

Unless your document defines `\bibinfo` different from `\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}` you will not see a difference in output between choosing `bibinfo` and not selecting it.

`\bibinfo` was mainly intended to give third parties with access to the `.bbl` file/`.tex` source of your bibliography a convenient way to uniquely and automatically reproduce the `.bib` entry. In a short search I haven't found any information online about tools actually using `\bibinfo` for that purpose and a look at the `.bst` files installed on my system suggests that only a few styles actually use `\bibinfo` (the `revtex`, `acmart`, `elsarticle`, ... families). I doubt it is used much.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations!
Did I understand correctly that I should use the default ("not tags") if I don't have a `\bibinfo` in my document?

Comment: @Soalpa It's not exactly about what you have in your document, it's more about what you want in your `.bbl` file. From an output perspective the two options will be the same unless you actively work against that.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it now. Thank you! :)