# How to produce bibs of the style used in the figure

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style

I need to produce bibs like those in the following figure.

[image: jcst-bib]

I am using `IEEEtran` and `IEEEabrv`. They produce bibs like these:

[image: ieee-bib]

The styles of both author names and titles (maybe others) are different.

***My problem is:*** How should I produce bibs of the desired style? (I *don't* have to use `IEEEtran` or `IEEEabrv`.)

---

My `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Book: \cite{Lamport:SS02}

Conference paper: \cite{Yuan:OSDI14}

Journal article: \cite{Imine:TCS06}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv, jcst}

\end{document}
```

My `.bib` file:

```
@book{Lamport:SS02,
 author = {Lamport, Leslie},
 title = {Specifying Systems: The {TLA$^+$} Language and Tools for Hardware and Software Engineers},
 year = {2002},
 isbn = {0-3211-4306-X},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley Longman Publishing Co., Inc.},
 address = {Boston, MA, USA},
} 

@article{Imine:TCS06,
 author = {Imine, Abdessamad and Rusinowitch, Micha\"{e}l and Oster, G{\'e}rald and Molli, Pascal},
 title = {Formal Design and Verification of Operational Transformation Algorithms for Copies Convergence},
 journal = {Theor. Comput. Sci.},
 volume = {351},
 number = {2},
 month = feb,
 year = {2006},
 pages = {167--183},
 doi = {10.1016/j.tcs.2005.09.066},
}

@inproceedings{Yuan:OSDI14,
 author = {Yuan, Ding and Luo, Yu and Zhuang, Xin and Rodrigues, Guilherme Renna and Zhao, Xu and Zhang, Yongle and Jain, Pranay U. and Stumm, Michael},
 title = {Simple Testing Can Prevent Most Critical Failures: An Analysis of Production Failures in Distributed Data-intensive Systems},
 booktitle = {Proceedings of the 11th USENIX Conference on Operating Systems Design and Implementation},
 series = {OSDI'14},
 year = {2014},
 pages = {249--265},
}
```

Comment: If you need this reference format because you are submitting to a journal, a conference or some other publisher, check if they have a LaTeX template (which often contains a BibTeX style or at least some hint as to what to do for BibTeX). Double check the submission guidelines and what they say about bibliographies (some publishers will post-process the bibliography anyway and accept submissions with a different, 'standard' bibliography style).

Comment: There are a great many styles out there and it may well be that there is already one that does what you need, but it may be hard to find. So you could also try using `custombib`'s `makebst` to create this style, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96174/35864.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I am preparing a paper for a journal. It is indeed a custom BibTeX style used by the journal. I have omitted it before. Great thanks.