# Detecting the pattern style used in the references inside of a book

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle, bst

[image: unknown bibliography style used in this image]

There is this book in which such a style is used. I created the bib file according to my knowledge; the first four entries are as follows:

```
@book{1,
  title={Elementary linear algebra},
  author={Anton, Howard and Rorres, Chris},
  edition={6},
  year={1991},
  publisher={Wiley, New York}
}

@book{2,
  title={Mathematical methods for physicists},
  author={Arfken, George B and Weber, Hans J},
  edition={4},
  year={1995},
  publisher={Academic Press},
  address={San Diego}
}

@book{3,
  title={Introduction to Bessel functions},
  author={Bowman, Frank},
  year={1958},
  publisher={Dover Publications},
  address={New York}
}

@book{4,
  title={Mathematical methods with applications to problems in the physical sciences},
  author={Bradbury, Ted Clay},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Wiley, New York}
}
```

In this picture, the output pattern with two authors goes in the following form:

```
(Last name, Name) and (Last name, Name.) Title of book, edition. publisher, address, series, year.
```

How do I determine which BibTeX (or BibLaTeX) style does this pattern resemble? Or, how can I create such a style using BibLaTeX and its settings?

These references are very similar to the `abbrv` style in the BibTeX engine and are arranged alphabetically by the first author's last name. But in this style, the last name comes first and the author's name comes after the comma without being abbreviated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a BibTeX (`.bst`) style you may want to look into using `custom-bib`'s `makebst` tool ([Is there an (easy) way to create or personalize .bst files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96174/35864)).

But since you have tagged the question with `biblatex` here is a `biblatex` implementation of that style (or rather the bits of the style visible in the picture) based on my [`biblatex-ext` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) to make the modification of the `edition` easier.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authortitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\mkbibordedition{#1}~\biblstring{edition}}
    {#1\isdot}}

\renewbibmacro*{edition}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{edition}}

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\publocdelim}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\locdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{anton,
  title     = {Elementary Linear Algebra},
  author    = {Anton, Howard and Rorres, Chris},
  edition   = {6},
  year      = {1991},
  publisher = {Wiley, New York}
}
@book{arfken,
  title     = {Mathematical Methods for Physicists},
  author    = {Arfken, George B. and Weber, Hans J.},
  edition   = {4},
  year      = {1995},
  publisher = {Academic Press},
  address   = {San Diego},
}
@book{bowman,
  title     = {Introduction to {Bessel} Functions},
  author    = {Bowman, Frank},
  year      = {1958},
  publisher = {Dover Publications},
  address   = {New York},
}
@book{bradbury,
  title     = {Mathematical Methods With Applications to Problems in the Physical Sciences},
  author    = {Bradbury, Ted Clay},
  year      = {1984},
  publisher = {Wiley},
  location  = {New York},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,anton,arfken,bowman,bradbury}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Anton, Howard and Rorres, Chris. Elementary Linear Algebra, 6th edition. Wiley, New York, 1991.]