# Merge many bibtex files and sort by year

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, sorting

I would like to merge many bibtex files and sort the combined file by year. I used \bibliography to merge but when I want it to order by year, it ordered by input file. So, each input file is sorted separately. Here is my code

```
    \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{file1,file2,file3}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Want you obtain a typeset reference list as exemplified by your code and @user187803 answer, or a comsolided bib file, as the title of the OP ask for? In the first case, it woukd be a good idea to edit your question and change its title accordingly.

Comment: When loaded like that BibTeX does not sort the files separately. All cited entries will be sorted by the sorting scheme specified by the bibliography style (in your case `plain` sorts by name first). If I understand your question correctly the only thing you need to change is the selected style, so you can force the desired order. Off the top of my head I don't know a BibTeX style that sorts by year first (though I have no doubt that there are such styles available already). You can create your own style with https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96174/35864).

Comment: You may want to check your tags. `biblatex` is incompatible with the classical BibTeX approach you are using at the moment as it completely reimplements LaTeX's citation and bibliography commands. It is easy enough to switch to `biblatex` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864), but some people prefer to stick to BibTeX for a variety of reasons.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864. It would help if you could either explicitly state that you are interested in a `biblatex` solution (if that is the case) or remove the tag to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `biblatex` you can sort by year e.g. using `sorting=ynt`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{file1.bib}
@book{a,
  author = {A},
  year = {2004},
  title = {A},
}
@book{b,
  author = {B},
  year = {2000},
  title = {B},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{file2.bib}
@book{c,
  author = {C},
  year = {2007},
  title = {C},
}
@book{d,
  author = {D},
  year = {2001},
  title = {D},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{file1.bib}
\addbibresource{file2.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you  so much, it works perfectly